Maintaining test isolation and not testing implementation with API wrappers
I'm new to Test Driven Development and I've been thinking about how to test some API wrappers which perform modifications on the received data so it complies with my own custom format. I ran into an issue when thinking about whether or not to mock the API in my tests. On the one hand, mocking seems to test implementation and not behavior since it's reaching into the internals of the class and interrogating how it calls the API. This overly couples my tests to my code. On the other hand, if I don't mock then how can I isolate the tests for the wrapper's data transformation logic?
One solution would be to separate the business logic from the API calls by creating a wrapper class for performing the API calls and another which transforms the data. However, the API of that wrapper class would effectively be tightly coupled to the external API. If the API changes, the data format returned by the wrapper class code would have to change, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid by transforming the data to a custom format in the first place. Making a class that returns the data "as is" just seems redundant. How could I design this system so that I don't test implementation and also maintain test isolation? Maybe I'm overthinking this whole issue, but I've just been going in circles mentally. I'd appreciate any insight from someone more experienced.

One can hardly give a single, unambiguous answer to such a question, since test-driven development (TDD) in itself serves more than one purpose:

As a process, through the act of writing a test before the implementation, one receives valuable feedback about the API and behaviour of the System Under Test (SUT). It frequently happens that the process unearths problems with one's original conceptual design. When that happens, an important step in TDD is to reset and try something else (Git has turned out to be quite helpful in this regard).
Once the tests and the design congeal and agree, the process leaves behind a set of automated tests that protect against regressions.

While there's a certain exploratory quality to TDD, it doesn't follow that planning ahead is forbidden. One should, however, be ready to discard any plans if it turns out that the reality (as indicated by the (test) code) doesn't fit the plans. Thus, while an hour of planning can save days of coding, too much planning often turns out to be wasted.
From the OP, it's hard to tell what purpose TDD is intended to serve. Is it to gather feedback on API design ideas? Or is it to create an automated test suite? If the latter, what kind of errors should the tests prevent?
The OP makes it sound as though the code to be driven by tests is mostly mapping code. This kind of code can be tedious to write, but how error-prone is it? How costly is a defect? Do you even need to test it?
Let us assume, however, for the sake of argument, that you need to test-drive this code. What are your options?
Dynamic mocks do, indeed, come with problems as outlined in the OP. What else can one do?
A typical object-oriented design may follow a template like the following pseudocode:
GetFooFromAPI(bar)
  apiBar = translate bar to API represenation
  apiFoo = invoke API with apiBar
  foo = translate API foo to external representation
  return foo

When designed this way, the API invocation looks like an integral part of the process. Many developers can't think of any other way of making such a design testable than replacing the API with some kind of Test Double.
And you can certainly do that, but if so, consider using state-based testing instead of interaction-based testing.
As is often the case, being aware of more than one programming paradigm can be helpful. In functional programming (FP), one would often model this kind of problem in a different way. Translation or mapping code can often be regarded as a set parser/writer pairs, or serializer/deserializer pairs.
In FP, one may view the overall action of translating one way, invoking the API, and translating back as function composition:
GetFooFromAPI(bar) = apiFooToFoo(invokeAPI(barToAPIBar(bar))

which one would write mathematically as
GetFooFromAPI = apiFooToFoo ∘ invokeAPI ∘ barToAPIBar

Westeners often find that right-to-left composition order counter-intuitive, so some languages offer other alternatives. In F#, for example, one might express the same idea as:
GetFooFromAPI = barToAPIBar >> invokeAPI >> apiFooToFoo

The point of this digression being that this isn't just an abstract mathematical notion, but a real, practical technique supported by actual, useful programming languages.
In FP, one would often consider function composition as a 'given' - as something not warranting testing, since it's typically built into the language, or at least a general-purpose library function. Thus, what remains to be tested are the translations.
And since such mappings typically are pure functions, they are intrinsically testable.
One could test each individual mapping, or instead test each parser/writer pair as there-and-back-again properties.
In conclusion, there are many options. Choose the one that best solves the problem at hand. This requires first figuring out what that problem is. The 'real' problem rarely is 'how do I TDD this?', but rather a more high-level problem to which TDD may or may not be the answer.
